# How to use sum operator of rxjs?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-pipeable-operators

Things I have tried include following where values is array of values of which I want to find the sum.

I have also added necessary functions from rxjs as follows:
I get an error saying

> typeError: Rx.Observable.from(...).sum is not a function

```
const { merge , interval ,from} = rxjs;
const { tap ,take ,sum } = rxjs.operators;   
             
var sumSource = Rx.Observable.from(values).sum(function (x) {
    return x;
});

var subscription = sumSource.subscribe(
    function (x) {
        console.log('Next: ' + x);
        x.target.value = x;
    },
    function (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
    },
    function () {
        console.log('Completed');
    }
);
```

Not much is available about sum on internet.Any inputs to fix and get the sum?

Comment: Can you use `reduce` instead? https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/reduce

Comment: I tried         var  observableSum = of(values);
        observableSum
        .reduce((total , currentVal)=>{ return total + currentVal },0)
        .subscribe({
            next : function(val){
                console.log(val)
            }
        }).  but still same error reduce is not a function

Comment: Shouldn't be `pipe` and not `.reduce`? Check how they `.pipe` in the link.

Comment: yes tried that but the input I get is values which is an array . so doing const a = of(values);
        const example = a.pipe(reduce((acc, val) => acc + val)); and subscribing to it gives me array and not the sum. Any way I can use array with obervables

Comment: Instead of `const a = of(values);`, try `const a = from(values);` (import { from } from 'rxjs';).

Comment: yes that worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **sum:** regarding the official rxjs github [repository](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operators/index.ts) they do not export/provide the [sum](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/sum.html) operator anymore.
- **reduce operator** [reduce](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/reduce) applies an accumulator function over the source Observable, and returns the accumulated result when the source completes.
- **scan operator** [scan](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/scan) applies an accumulator function over the source Observable and returns the accumulated result every emit.

**setup**

```
const values = [1,2,3,4,5];
const accumulator = (acc, curr) => acc + curr;
```

**implement reduce**

```
from(values).pipe(
  reduce(accumulator, 0)
)
// Expected output: 15
```

**implement scan**

```
from(values).pipe(
  scan(accumulator, 0)
)
// expected output: 1, 3, 6, 10, 15
```

I made a running stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-reduce-vs-scan-behavior).

Comment: What if they array values are changing dynamically from input then the sum won't get updated automatically right? How are we supposed to do it

Comment: sum is not a thing anymore. I don't understand your question. from(values) is only an example source. If you want values to change over time, consider pushing them into a subject so your pipe is updated over time.